ThreeJS GLB Model not showing
I tried to render a basic 3d model using the ThreeJS libary in my Typescript project, but its not displaying at all.

The logs show the progress and no errors.
Source:
(Main)
import FaceInstance from './FaceInstance'

new FaceInstance();

import * as THREE from "three";

import {GLTFLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";

export default class FaceInstance extends THREE.Scene {
    private gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();

    private scene: THREE.Scene | undefined;

    private camera: THREE.Camera | undefined;

    private width = window.innerWidth;
    private height = window.innerHeight;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.initScene();
        this.initFace();
    }

    initFace() {
        this.gltfLoader.load("assets/model.glb",
            (gltf) => {
                if(!this.scene) return;
                this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
                this.render();
            },

            (xhr) => {
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("An error happened: ", error);
            }
        );
    }

    initScene() {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // Create a camera
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, this.width / this.height, 0.1, 1000);
        this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 5); // Move the camera back along the z-axis

        // Create a directional light
        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 0); // Set the light direction
        this.scene.add(directionalLight);

        // Add ambient light to the scene
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
        this.scene.add(ambientLight);
    }

    render() {
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: document.getElementById('app') as HTMLCanvasElement
        });
        renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
        if(!this.camera) return;
        renderer.render(this, this.camera)
    }
}

This is the html page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Getting Started with Three.js</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
           margin: 0;
           height: 100%;
        }
        #app {
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           display: block;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="app"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>

I tried almost everything that I found on ThreeJS docs and on various other pages. (Example: Adding Light, Changing the Cam position, etc.)
I expect my model to show.

One common cause would be insufficient lighting. Try setting scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x505050) so that if the model is dark, you'll still see its silhouette. Or perhaps the model is too large, small, or far from the origin. Try logging new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(gltf.scene) and inspect the min/max bounds of the model's bounding box.
